# How to rspec test redirect_to with session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Here is one line of code in the `update` action of `Customers` controller. How to test the `redirect_to` in RSpec?

```
 redirect_to session[('page' + session[:page_step].to_s).to_sym], :notice => 'Customer was updated successfaully!'
```

Any thoughts? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
it "redirects to the next step" do
  # assign the current step
  session[:page_step] = "next"

  put :update
  response.should redirect_to("pagenext")
end
```

Also note you have a typo in your code: `successfaully`. You can simplify your code to

```
redirect_to session[:"page#{session[:page_step]}"], :notice => 'Customer was updated successfully!'
```